# Restoring terminal state with curses like vim

Tags: screen, reset, curses

I'm writing a program using curses to display information on the screen.

After the program exits, the contents of the screen remain the same. In programs such as vim, the terminal is restored to its state before the program was run.

I am wondering how to replicate this behaviour.

I am calling `endwin` to restore terminal settings.